# How do we design a spring integration system where from the first call response we will have to decide which gateway to follow

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

**Spring Integration:**Need to design a system where from the first call response it will be decided which gateway to go to in the spring integration.

Was trying to implement first gateway as the common call then another gateway to segregate the different gateway calls. As we need gateway for the first interaction.Looking for other better design than this.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post the code in here due to security reason but i think using gateway for the first interaction and then based on the response if we use the router for segregating the call would help over here. Thanks!!